# Looping Eliminate tool in Python?

Tags: arcpy, python, loop, tools, eliminate

I am very new at Python,I'm not sure if this is even the appropriate way to do what I want to do, but basically, I'm looking to eliminate all of the small polygons in a feature class that was created to show all of the watershed basins of an area. I will need to run the Eliminate tool multiple times to eliminate all polygons smaller than an acre (since sometimes the tool will combine 2 small polygons and they still end up being less than an acre). Right now I can run the eliminate tool once with:

```
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(basinFC,basinLYR)
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(basinLYR,"NEW_SELECTION","Acres < 1")
arcpy.management.Eliminate(basinLYR,basin_elim)
```

Since I've never used a loop in Python before, I'm not sure which to use or where to place it.

Comment: To learn about Python for loops I suggest using Google to find tutorials like https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop for a set number of iterations would look like this:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True #make sure you can overwrite the eliminate output
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(basinFC,basinLYR) 
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(basinLYR,"NEW_SELECTION","Acres < 1") 
elim = arcpy.Eliminate_management(basinLYR,basin_elim)
iter = 5 #number of iterations -- how many times to go through the loop

for i in range(iter):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(elim,elimLYR)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(elimLYR,"NEW_SELECTION","Acres < 1") 
    elim = arcpy.Eliminate_management(elimLYR,'_'.join([basin_elim,str(i)]))
```

Comment: This will just run eliminate on `basinLYR` 5 times. You need to feed the output of `eliminate` to the input of the next loop.

Comment: FIxed - elim now feeds back into the loop.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: A while loop might be better here - 'while number of features selected under criteria x is >0, keep running the tool'

Comment: When I try the above mentioned I receive the error: "ERROR 000670: output Output Feature Class is same as input Input Layer.
Failed to execute (Eliminate)." The error is referring to the last line of code. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using a gdb try my edit above.  You need to change the name of the elim layer each time so you're not trying to overwrite it in place.